# How to us openid connect hybrid flow to call an Api on behalf of user (IdentityServer4 Asp.Net Core 2.0)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am attempting to use IdentityServer4 to have a web application call an API on behalf of the user. I expect that the API will have the User Identity information for the user even though it is the web application making the request.

Everything is working correctly (Authentication/Claims etc) except within the API `User.Identity.Name` is null. User.Identity.Name in the Web application is returning the correct username. bellow is an example of what I have tried.

I am using 
IdentityServer4 v- 2.1.2
IdentityModel   v- 3.1.1
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All v- 2.0.5

Just as some backround: I am folowing a PluralSight Tutorial - https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnet-core-identity-management-playbook/table-of-contents

API Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api")]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    [Route("user")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult GetUser()
    {
        return Content("User " + User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

API Startup.cs - ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44335";
        options.Audience = "DemoApi";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

IdentityServer InMemory Client setup

```
new Client()
{
    ClientId = "WebApp",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
    ClientSecrets = new [] {new Secret("MySecret".Sha256())},
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "DemoApi"
    },
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44343/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "https://localhost:44343/signout-callback-oidc"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    RequireConsent = false
}
```

IdentityServer TestUser setup:

```
new TestUser()
{
    SubjectId = "1",
    Username = "testname",
    Password = "pass123",
    Claims = new []
    {
        new Claim("name", "testname")
    }
}
```

Web Application startup.cs ConfigureServices Method - Authentication setup

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
}).AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44335/";
    options.ClientId = "WebApp";
    options.ClientSecret = "MySecret";
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    options.Scope.Add("DemoApi");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
}).AddCookie();
```

Web Application API call -

```
[Route("callapi")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
{
    string accessToken;
    try
    {
        accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.Error = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
        return View();
    }

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    try
    {
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44379/api/user");
        ViewBag.ApiResponse = content;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ApiResponse = ex.GetBaseException().Message;                
    }

    ViewBag.AccessToken = accessToken;
    ViewBag.RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);

    return View();
}

private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    var exp = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
    var expires = DateTime.Parse(exp);

    if (expires > DateTime.Now)
    {
        return await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
    }

    return await GetRefreshedAccessToken();
}

private async Task<string> GetRefreshedAccessToken()
{
    var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44335/");
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "WebApp", "MySecret");
    var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);

    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
    {
        var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        auth.Properties.UpdateTokenValue(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, tokenResponse.AccessToken);
        auth.Properties.UpdateTokenValue(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, tokenResponse.RefreshToken);
        var expiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn);
        auth.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("expires_at", expiresAt.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, auth.Principal, auth.Properties);
        return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
    }

    throw tokenResponse.Exception;
}
```

API - User.Identity
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting up your API according to the [official documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html).

From what I see, the differences are in the authentication type. You have

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options => 
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:44335";
                options.Audience = "DemoApi";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            });
```

while the docs say:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ApiName = "api1";
        });
```

Of course modify it with your authority url. The other things seem legit.

PS: The `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` is coming with `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package

**EDIT**

Based on comments - remove this lines:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
```

And lets see what happens.

**EDIT 2**

After some discussions, we figured out that Zzz was using some Pluralsight tutorial for asp.net identity. For those who are reading this, and they are starting implementing IdentityServer as an authentication for their applications - follow the official [documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html) and also check the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples).

PS: And always enable logging. It is everything and saves tons of hours.

Comment: I tried your suggestions.  User.Identity.Name was still null in the API method.

Comment: What about claims and so on. Do you have them? Is the object a claims identity ?

Comment: The TestUser has a "name" claim of "testname".  This claim is returned from IdentityServer and is accessible in the Web Application.

Comment: I'm asking about within the API. Within the API method, the User.Identity object - what type is it, and if it is claims identity, do you see the claims there?

Comment: Take a look at the screen capture I added to the question. It shows the User.Identity.Claims in the API project.

Comment: Updated the answer a bit

Comment: With my version of the code and these lines removed the API returns a 500;

Comment: With your version of the code and the lines removed the API returns a 401.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165737/discussion-between-m3n7alsnak3-and-zzz).